# How to disable React Hook "useCallback" cannot be called inside a callback warning?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have created a utility hook that allow updating the state of components as long as they are mounted.

to do so, I had to call `useCallack` inside the callback function of `Array.map`
this is my code

```
export const useSafeDispatches = (...dispatches) => {
    const mounted = useRef(false);
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        mounted.current = true;
        return () => (mounted.current = false);
    }, []);

    return dispatches.map((dispatch) =>
        useCallback((...args) => (mounted.current ? dispatch(...args) : void 0), [dispatch])
    );
};
```

I am getting this error when I try to build
 `React Hook "useCallback" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says exactly what you need to do, pull `useCallback` out of the `map` callback. Your callback depends on the value of `mounted.current`, so we make sure to include it in our list of dependencies -

```js
export const useSafeDispatches = (...dispatches) => {
    
    const mounted = useRef(false);

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        mounted.current = true;
        return () => (mounted.current = false);
    }, []);

    const safeDispatch = useCallback(dispatch =>
      (...args) => mounted.current ? dispatch(...args) : void 0
    , [mounted.current]);

    return dispatches.map(safeDispatch);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me.
You have an extra closing brace before `[mounted.current]`

Comment: Happy to help. Thanks for the review, I fixed the typo :D